# Чередование потоков

Tags: c, mutex, condition-variable, qnx

Однопроцессная программа содержит 6 потоков. Каждый поток выполняет свою поточную функцию в бесконечном цикле. В поточной функции выводится идентификатор потока tid, далее поток засыпает на 1 секунду, и, проснувшись, передаёт управление следующему потоку (1, 2, .., 6, 1...). Программа должна воспроизвести несколько циклов заданного чередования потоков, после чего принудительно завершается.

Вот мой код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
 
typedef struct {
int id;
} param;
static int current = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condvar = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void *function(void *arg)
{
 param * thread_number = (param*)arg;
 while(1)
 {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while (thread_number->id != current) pthread_cond_wait(&condvar,&mutex);
  if (thread_number->id == current)
  {
   printf("THIS IS THREAD #%d OF PROCESS #%d\n", pthread_self(), getpid());
   current = (current + 1) % 6
   //sleep(1);
  }
 }
 pthread_cond_signal(&condvar);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main()
{
 int i;
 param p;
 pthread_t threads[6];
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
  p.id = i;
  pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, function, (void*)&p);
  sleep(1);
 }
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

В main'е я в цикле создаю 6 потоков с помощью pthread_create, передаю им счётчик цикла и потом использую его в качестве номера процесса. Потом жду их завершения с помощью pthread_join.

В первый раз всё хорошо, все 6 потоков отрабатывают, но потом они зависают и не работают. Посмотрел в pidin (запускаю в qnx v6.3.2, после 1 прогонки все потоки находятся в состоянии condvar (см. вложения). Помогите исправить =(
[image: вложения]

Comment: не шарю в c, просто предположу, может ли ваша программа застраять тут? `while (thread_number->id != current) pthread_cond_wait(&condvar,&mutex);` - наппример, при `current` равному такому числу, которого нет в потоках, типа 0 или 8 ?

Comment: `pthread_cond_signal()` должен быть внутри цикла — иначе другие процессы не узнают, что условие изменилось... ЗЫ: и в вопросе что-то не так с фигурными скобками...

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем смысл вашей многопоточности, если у вас поочередно выполнение?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, забыл дописать одну } в конце при копировании. Перенёс `pthread_cond_signal()` в цикл if, но проблема не решилась, более того, потоки начали работать вразнобой

Comment: @tym32167, да нет, программа берёт остаток от деления `current` на 6, то есть её значение будет в интервале [0,5], которые я и использую для потоков

Comment: ваш код не стыкуется с реальностью (не вызываются сигналы вообще). покажите полностью вместе с main.

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);` внутри бесконечного цикла `while(1)` приведёт к неопределёнки или мёртвому зависанию. Лочить нужно **перед** этим циклом.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, Добавил main в вопрос. Перестановка мьютекс лока не помогла, в pidin всё равно пишет, что потоки в состоянии condvar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде несколько проблем:

- `pthread_cond_signal()` будит только один из процессов ожидающих  на условной переменной. т.к. процессы ожидают разных условий, не факт, что им окажется именно тот процесс, который идёт в очереди следующим. Нужно использовать `pthread_cond_broadcast()`
- Сигнал другим процессам на пробуждение (`pthread_cond_broadcast()`) должен находиться внутри цикла — иначе ни кто не будут уведомляться об изменении условия
- Множественный вызов `pthread_mutex_lock()` для одного и того же мьютекса одним и тем же процессом — вообще говоря, UB (если мьютекс не инициализирован как `ERRORLOCK`). Надо или вынести `pthread_mutex_lock()` из цикла или внести `pthread_mutex_unlock()` внутрь.
- В `main()` все потоки запускаются с одним и тем же экземпляром `param`: он передаётся всем потокам по указателю, который указывает на один участок памяти. Каждому потоку нужно передавать свой экземпляр.

В общем должно быть как-то так:

```
void *function(void *arg)
{
 param * thread_number = (param*)arg;
 while(1)
 {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while (thread_number->id != current) pthread_cond_wait(&condvar,&mutex);
  if (thread_number->id == current)
  {
   printf("THIS IS THREAD #%d OF PROCESS #%d\n", pthread_self(), getpid());
   current = (current + 1) % 6
   //sleep(1);
  }
  pthread_cond_broadcast(&condvar);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 }
}

int main()
{
 int i;
 param p[6];
 pthread_t threads[6];
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
  p[i].id = i;
  pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, function, &p[i]);
  sleep(1);
 }
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```